# Save form data to session, repopulate form with it on refresh (Symfony)

Tags: php, symfony

I'm willing to save a form (created with FormBuilder) on submit to the session. As soon as the user comes back to the same page, the form should be repopulated with the previous submitted information in case it exist.

```
    // Create form
    $form = $this->createForm(MappingType::class, $mapping);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    // Populate it if we already have data from the request or from session, only when not submitted
    if (!$form->isSubmitted() && $request->getSession()->has('mapping')) {
       $form->setData($request->getSession()->get('mapping'));
    }

    // Save form data to session
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $request->getSession()->set('mapping', $form->getData());
    }
```

The MappingType form is with children, but also a field on top level doesn't seem to get populated again. The Children mainly consist of ChoiceType fields.

The session data is populated with all form data. And as I'm not using Doctrine, but just a plain entity, I see no issues with persistence.

The form gets populated correctly on the POST request (handleRequest), but not when I just load it again (GET).

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you move the bloc which set the data before the `handleRequest`?

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't change anything, @Veve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Veve said you must set data before create form like that  :

```
if($request->getSession()->has('mapping'))) {
    $mapping->setSomething('value');
    $mapping->setSomethingOhter('value');
}
$form = $this->createForm(MappingType::class, $mapping);
```

**Edit**

If object exist for example in data base

```
$mapping = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Object')->findBy('field'=>'value');
$form = $this->createForm(MappingType::class, $mapping);
```

Comment: Alright, but takes a lot of manual work. Would it be possible to just insert all the request data again as I'm trying in my initial post? I don't get that to work. I wouldn't like to iterate over all fields and set them one by one, that feels inefficient.

Comment: So basically what I want it to store the form data ($form->getData()) into the session and set it on the form later on again. It's quite a complicated form with several children in it, so therefore I was hoping to use such a method. Depending on the file uploaded by user the form is also different each time.

Comment: The shortcut is to take the $request->getSession()->get('mapping') and use it in the 'createForm' call. My problem was that I had children form fields, and they were using sub instances of classes, which made it not working. Adjusting this made it work, so I think this is the requested answer as it kept me looking for the proper way to do it.